# Validation for Ajax array in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am posting post data from form. I want to validate that array in controller and send a json response to the ajax call. Can you please help me with it.

This is my controller function code where I am submitting form.

```
public function submit()
{

    $data=array(
        'user_firstname'=>$_POST['user_firstname'],
        'user_lastname'=>$_POST['user_lastname'],
        'user_phone'=>$_POST['user_phone'],
        'email'=>$_POST['user_email'],
        'username'=>$_POST['user_username'],
        'password'=>$_POST['user_password'],

    );
     $validation=validator($_POST);
    if($validation->passes()){

      return "Validation passes";

    }
    else{
        return "Validation failed";
    }
}

 protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'user_firstname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'user_lastname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'user_phone' => 'required|string|max:15|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

This is my javascript function.

```
 if(currentTab==2)
{

$.ajax({
      url: "register", 
      type: "post",
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      data: {'user_firstname':user_firstname,'user_lastname':user_lastname,'user_phone':user_phone,'user_email':user_email,'user_username':user_username,'user_password':user_password},
      success: function(result){
         console.log(result);
        }
    });

}
```

I want to validate the array and return all the errors in json following is my validator in the same controller.

Please suggest me if there is another way to validate data

**Validation is passing every test even with empty array**

Comment: Put this code in else part: `$error = true;
            $responsecode = 400;
            $result["error_message"] = "";
            if (sizeof($validator->errors()->getMessages()) > 0){
                $messages = $validator->errors()->getMessages();
                foreach ($messages as $key => $value) {
                    $result["error_message"] .= $value[0] .' ';
                }
            }`

Comment: i dont know whats the problem but its passing every validation test

Comment: First, do you want to print all errors or anything else?

Comment: yes i want to print errors

Comment: Then read my first comment! I have gave code for it! If you don't understand let me know.

Comment: yes but my validation is not working correct

Comment: You mean it's not validate if you send empty request data?

Comment: no no when i enter an existing email id or existing username it still passing the test and in validation rules i have written unique

Comment: Try like this: `'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email',`

Comment: its still passing the validation is there anything wrong in implementation

Comment: or is there another way

Comment: Try only this in email: `'email' => 'required|unique:users,email'`

Comment: same error is showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your code and you can try with this code:

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
   $error = false; 
   $result = array();
   $responsecode = 200;

   $validator = Validator::make($request, [
            'user_firstname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'user_lastname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'user_phone' => 'required|string|max:15|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users,username',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
   ]);

   if (!empty($request) && !($validator)){
        try {
            $result = 'Validate!!';     //OR do more your stuff here
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            $error = true;
            $responsecode = 500; 
            $result["error_message"] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        $error = true;
        $responsecode = 400;
        $result["error_message"] = "";
        if (sizeof($validator->errors()->getMessages()) > 0){
            $messages = $validator->errors()->getMessages();
            foreach ($messages as $key => $value) {
                 $result["error_message"] .= $value[0] .' ';
            }
        }
     }
}
```

I have used this type of format everytime, try it.

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Thanks a lot man worked like charm thanks a lot seriouly u saved my job

Comment: Glad, it helps!! :) This is the format/structure of code to save data and for api with every response code!